# PostgreSQL grouping query for count field as part of smth and the total count field

Tags: sql, postgresql, analytics

I have the table:
table 1 (product_id,purchase_date, city, market, category)

categories = ('bread','soap','vegetables','fruits')

I need result in one table (following columns):
purchase_date, city, market,  count of vegetable products, count of all products

grouping is carried out by the first three fields to be able to use the first three fields as filters

Comment: What is the problem? What have you tried?

Comment: So `category` is a `jsonb` (or `json`) column?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You want conditional aggregation.  In Postgres, I recommend `filter`:

```
SELECT purchase_date, city, market
       COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE category = 'vegetables') as cnt_vegetables,
       COUNT(*) as cnt
FROM table1
WHERE market = ? AND city = ? AND purchase_date = ?
GROUP BY purchase_date, city, market;
```

Answer (score 0):

Disable where clause if not needed.

```
-- PostgreSQL
SELECT purchase_date
     , city
     , market
     , SUM(CASE WHEN category = 'vegetables' THEN 1 END) "count of vegetable products"
     , COUNT(1) "count of all products"
FROM table1
WHERE market = ? AND city = ? AND purchase_date = ?
GROUP BY purchase_date;
     , city
     , market
```

Comment: Hi @bwoah please check my query and let me know if any query regard this.

Comment: Unrelated but: `count(1)` is actually slightly slower than `count(*)` in case you assumed the constant value is some kind of magic performance improvement.

Comment: Hi @a_horse_with_no_name use 1 instead of * performs better when when handling large volume of data.

Comment: No, it does not. For all databases except Postgres, there is absolutely no difference in performance between `count(*)` and `count(1)`. And as I wrote in Postgres `count(1)` is actually slightly _slower_. See e.g. this blog post: https://blog.jooq.org/2019/09/19/whats-faster-count-or-count1/

Comment: @Rahul Biswas, your comment helped a lot, thanks!

Comment: Hi @bwoah is my given answer helpful to you? Or it meets your expected result.

Comment: @Rahul Biswa you helped me solve my problem, thanks!

Comment: So @bwoah please mark my answer as accepted and useful. If anyone search related this in future he/she first check whether it is marked or not. That's why I'm asking you. Please don't take it otherwise. Thanks

Comment: I don't have enough reputation, but my vote is recorded

Comment: Hi @bwoah my answer helped you a lot which you mentioned in message. But today I saw you've marked my answer as 0 vote. I didn't understand that.

Comment: @Rahul Biswa  as I said earlier I don't have enough reputation to vote

Comment: @bwoah thanks for response. But you can give a up vote as this answer helped you. Zero vote means this answer isn't help you.